# Is there a geometrical representation of classical bits, like that of the Bloch Sphere for quantum bits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, information, bloch-sphere

Consider only a single qubit. We know that it can be accurately described using the so called Bloch Sphere. Is there a similar geometric construction used to describe classical bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the two states 'up' and 'down' of a little arrow, one constrained to point only in those two directions, if you like. However this picture does not on its own offer much.

A geometric picture of great use in classical information theory is the one called 'Hamming space'. This is a discrete space of $n$ dimensions if there are $n$ bits. Some examples give the idea:

1 bit: the states 0,1 are situated on the two ends of a unit line.

2 bits: the states 00,01,10,11 are situated on the four corners of a unit square.

3 bits: the states 000,001,... 111 are situated on the eight corners of a unit cube.

etc.

In every case the corners are labelled such that each corner differs from its neighbours in only one bit.

This picture is useful for studying how far apart one bit string is from another, in the sense of how many bits you have to flip to move from one to the other. It is equal to the number of edges you have to traverse on the relevant $n$-dimensional cube.

I guess there are also other geometric pictures that can be invoked.

Comment: "1 bit: the states 0,1 are situated on the two ends of a unit line.". I see what you mean but I think that does not represents the whole picture. I am looking for a geometric picture that encapsulates both the state and the probability of observing that state. How can we integrate the probability of being +1 with probability p and -1  with probability of (1-p) to the picture you are talking about?

Comment: @GGGGGGÜNSSSSSSSÜER A classical probability distribution over n states can be represented by an (n-1)-simplex. For 1 bit there are two states and you get a line segment (the same as the Hamming picture in this case). For 2 bits there are 4 states and you get a tetrahedron.